# upgrading python

Tags: python

My dedicated server is centos with Cpanel. I need to upgrade python for [eyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/) program. How do I upgrade to latest python stable? From cPanel or SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use CentOS, yum provide update python. You can update Python to >= 2.5 at your own risk.

I recommendation install new version Python in /opt.

Comment: what risks are possible ?

Comment: @ahmet CentOS uses python 2.5 for a lot of internal things. yum is one of the biggies. Basically, its par for the course that you just install a version of python from source in the /opt/ directory. It ends up being cleaner all around.

Answer (score 2):

A good practice for this is installing another version of Python side by side with the system provided one, python on CentOS (and most Linux distros) is very heavily tied with the operating system, upgrading the system one to a new version is not recommendable.

I normally add a new python repo and point my program to use that version of python instead, there's an amazing guide for installing python side by side (you'll need shell access for this), check it out here http://www.question-defense.com/2009/12/25/how-to-install-python-2-6-on-centos-5-without-breaking-yum

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is via SSH. 
Download the latest python version or use Yum (or yum search for specific packages). After that add the new version of python to PATH if necessary, and configure the application to use that path (of the newly installed python). 
[Here](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-centos-rhel/) how you can download python and install it: